# Android: Properly cleaning up after OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

Are there any specific cleanup actions that need to be taken to clean up after using OpenGL ES on Android or does everything happen automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whereas the OS should clean up any OpenGL resources (like textures, VBOs, the framebuffer, ...) once your program ends (this should hold on Android like for any other OS) or the GL context is destroyed, it is still good practice to delete any OpenGL objects once they're not needed anymore using their respective destructors (like `glDeleteTextures`, `glDeleteBuffers`, ...).